# AppleTV Focusing CollectionView elements in TableView

Tags: swift, apple-tv, focus-engine

I'm building an app for AppleTV which has a UITableView. I made a custom cell for it, which has a UILabel and a UICollectionView. Is there a way to make both the label and the elements of the collection view focusable? I tried making both table view's canFocusRowAt and collection view's canFocusItemAt to return true, but its not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionViewCell/UITableViewCell` are not focus appearance by default, we need to override the below function in `subclass` of `UICollectionViewCell/UITableViewCell` and do the focus settings.

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if isFocused {
        //Apply your focused appearance
    }else{
        //Apply normal appearance
    }
}
```

Also if you have just a `UIImageView` in your `collectionViewCell` then you can just do below in your `awakeFromNib`:

```
myImageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
clipsToBounds = false
```